# Split strings from a file but use them as double

Tags: java, string, file, split

I have this text file which contains a column for account numbers and another for balances

```
1001 50.67
1002 500.32
1003 63.63
1004 953.53
1005 735.22
```

I would like to write a program that asks the user to enter his account number, for example 1002, then I would like to return the balance associated with it from the file, which is 500.31 in this case. I also want to be able to add (deposit) or subtract (withdraw) amounts from the balance, then update the text file. What is the best way to do it?
I wouldn't have problems with the deposit or withdraw methods, but I would like to know how is it possible to split the two numbers as strings but then still use the balances as double when adding or subtracting.

Comment: The *balances* **are not** integers. And try `System.out.println(0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05);` to understand why you want to use `BigDecimal` with money.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is similar to

```
1001 50.67
```

Then you separate using space as delimiter using something similar to following

```
str = "1001 50.67";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

You can convert the second value to double using code like

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(splited[1]);
```

and then proceed to do the changes you want to do.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if using Map would be the best for this scenario but then again it can give you easier checking for correspoding balance of each account.

You can serve the account numbers as the *key* of the Map and the balance as its corresponding *value*.

```
Map balancesOfEachAccount = new HashMap<String, Double>()
//with this, you can either treat the account number as double also. 
//however, it would be good to treat it as String since you won't be 
//doing any special operation for it as a double, you only want the 
//account number as something that indicates the balances so string is enough.
```

Wih regards to extracting data from a text file, you may use FileReader. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

In the issue towards separating each line to keys and values for your map you can use *StringTokenizer* of java: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Please also take note if the text file you'll be using will only contain 2 separate strings for each line, otherwise you need to add additional handling for it.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1001 50.67"); //retrieved from text via file reader
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
     //implement mapping here, 
     //1001 as key and 50.67 converted to Double as its value in map
 }
 //rest of your code
```

Note also that StringTokenizer has default delimeter, so when the text file changes its formatting as to how it separates account number and its corresponding balance, you might need to add changes to your parser for this one. You can specify the delimeter too as shown on link provided above.

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)
```

hope this helps.